# RegEx: Match after certain string is found otherwise select all

Tags: php, regex

I want to select everything after `& amazon -`. 
If it is not found the whole string should be returned

String:

```
'adidas & amazon - cool shirt'
```

Best thing I came up is this:

`(?(?=.*\bamazon\b)(\bamazon\b \- (.+ *))|(.*))`

But it also returns the amazon part.

Comment: please mention the language? `(?<=&\samazon\s-).*|^(?:(?!\samazon\s-).)*$`

Answer (score 1):

The below regexes would work for you.

```
(?<=&\samazon\s-).*|^(?!.*&\samazon\s-).*$
```

`(?<=&\samazon\s-).*` matches all the characters which are just after to `&` space amazon space hyphen.

`^(?!.*&\samazon\s-).*$` Matches the whole line which didn't have `& amazon -` string.

Change `\s` to `\h` if you want to deal only with the horizontal spaces.

**OR**

```
&\s*amazon\s*-\K.*|^(?!.*\samazon\s-).*$
```

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing out at the final. This does the job of variable length positive lookebhind assertion.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8lQ6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?|(?:.*?&\s*amazon\s*-\s*)(.*)|(.*))$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH4iB6/1)

You matched data will be available in captured group #1.

Here `(?|...)` is a non-capturing group that **makes sure that all the captured groups within this bracket start with same index** i.e. 1.

This regex is using simple regex alternation. On LHS we have:

```
(?:.*?&\s*amazon\s*-\s*)(.*)
```

Which puts string after `& amazon -` into captured group #1

On RHS we just have:

```
(.*)
```

Which puts whole line into captured group #1 itself (due to use of `(?|...)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern you had before with a slight adjustment should work:

```
(?(?=.*&\s\bamazon\b).+)(.+\-\s(.+))
```

If you wanted this to match `amazon` regardless of where it was before `-` you could use:

```
(?(?=.*\bamazon\b).+)(.+\-\s(.+))
```

Examples:

https://regex101.com/r/kK3hP0/1 // matches `& amazon` before `-`

https://regex101.com/r/nG3yK8/1 // matches `amazon` anywhere before `-`